# Regex to find and replace every character except one perticular word

Tags: regex, search, replace

I have a string something like this,

```
*********************KARTHIK**************
```

in which * may be of any character. I want to remove those characters and eventually the variable should have the string

```
KARTHIK
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search using this regex:

```
^.*?(KARTHIK).*$
```

Replace using:

```
$1
```

Comment: $1 does not work in my case. However replacing with "KARTHIK" works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the padding char (and always have a padding char), you can use this expression:

```
(.)\1*(?<result>.+?)\1
```

The match, if any, will contain the string in the capture group named "result".

Here's a demo and an explanation of the pattern: https://regex101.com/r/yE3xZ9/1